# Turning single function to multiple elements using each through error

Tags: jquery

I written a function to customize the html5 video controler. it works fine, later i have no.of instance within a page, so i turned the function, using each to multiple elements, but it throws the error..

what is wrong with my function? suggestion please..

myfunction :

```
var videoProcess = function (videoHolder) {
    var videoContainer = videoHolder,
        videoElement = videoContainer.find('video'),
        videoControler = videoContainer.find('span');

    videoControler.add(videoElement).bind('click',function () {
        videoElement.get(0).paused === false ?  videoElement.get(0).pause() : videoElement.get(0).play();
        videoElement.get(0).ended === true ? videoElement.get(0).play() : videoElement.get(0).ended === true;
    } );

    videoElement.bind('play',function () {
        videoControler.hide().removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
    } )

    videoElement.bind('ended',function () {
        videoControler.show().removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
    } )

    videoContainer.mouseleave(function () {
        videoContainer.mouseenter(function () {
            videoControler.show();    
        } ).mouseleave(function () {
            if(videoElement.get(0).paused === false && videoElement.get(0).ended === false ){
                videoControler.hide();    
            }

        } )    
    } )

    videoElement.bind('pause',function () {
        videoControler.show().removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
    } )
}

$(document).ready(function () {
     if($('video').length){
        $.each($('.video-holder'), function(num,val){ // i have no.of video-holder
            videoProcess(val);    
        } )
    }
} );
```

the error i am getting :

```
TypeError: videoContainer.find is not a function [Break On This Error]  

videoElement = videoContainer.find('video'),
```

updated function :

```
var videoProcess = function (videoHolder) {
    var videoContainer = $(videoHolder),
        videoElement = videoContainer.find('video'),
        videoControler = videoContainer.find('span');

    videoControler.add(videoElement).bind('click',function () {
        videoElement.get(0).paused === false ?  videoElement.get(0).pause() : videoElement.get(0).play();
        videoElement.get(0).ended === true ? videoElement.get(0).play() : videoElement.get(0).ended === true;
    } );

    videoElement.bind('play',function () {
        videoControler.hide().removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
    } )

    videoElement.bind('ended',function () {
        videoControler.show().removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
    } )

    videoContainer.mouseleave(function () {
        videoContainer.mouseenter(function () {
            videoControler.show();    
        } ).mouseleave(function () {
            if(videoElement.get(0).paused === false && videoElement.get(0).ended === false ){
                videoControler.hide();    
            }

        } )    
    } )

    videoElement.bind('pause',function () {
        videoControler.show().removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
    } )
}

$(document).ready(function () {   
    if($('video').length){
        $('.video-holder').each(videoProcess($(this)));
    }

} );
```

html: repeats no.of times

```
        <div class="video-holder">
            <video autobuffer poster="images/common-poster.png">
                <source src="Video/webm/Task_1.0_Host_treated.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source src="Video/ogv/Task_1.0_Host_treated.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <source src="Video/MP4/Task_1.0_Host_treated.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <span class="play">play th is</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: HTML added, it is repeating no.of times within page

Answer (score 1):

I got the fix, i called my function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if($('video').length){
        $('.video-holder').each(function(num,element) {
            videoProcess(element);
        });
}

});
```

Nothing special, i added a parameter as 'num', before i tried with single parameter, so it had only wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code so it's like this...

```
var videoContainer = $(videoHolder),
    videoElement = videoContainer.find('video'),
    videoControler = videoContainer.find('span');
```

You need to convert `videoHolder` to a jQuery object.

Comment: Can you give more information?  What is actually happening, and what errors are you receiving?

Comment: TypeError: c is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...,h=h.slice(c.length),c.type=g,c.matches=d);if(!c)break}return b?h.length:h?bc.er...

Comment: Scrap that - I can see what your problem is.  Changing the answer.

Comment: still i am getting the error... like what i shown above, as well all the video work like single controller.

Comment: So you wrapped `videoHolder` with `$()` and it still gives the same error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17819/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-archer)

Comment: i got the fix. thanks for you spared a lot time for me... thanks again.

Comment: Would you mind posting your fix for people that find this thread due to having a similar problem?  Thanks :)